# How to query data from database in a PHP page only once, and use it in multiple PHP pages?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mongodb, session

I am making a PHP website containing mulptiple pages and the data I am displaying in those pages is thousands of records/rows coming from a database table.

In each PHP page, a connection is established, a database is selected, a table is selected, and it is queried and data is returned and that data is modified. This *identical* process is repeated in each of the multiple PHP pages.

Now one option is that one should pass around that huge dataset between pages (using POST?) using

Is there a way to perform the above steps only once in a PHP page and then store that data somewhere temporarily for the session. So that it is available to all PHP pages.

Comment: For these kind of architecture you must use caching. Memcahce/Redis is the best one.

Comment: Do you mean records paging? i.e pagination?

Comment: you can include one page like.... include('youfilename.php');

Comment: If you need to store data that is on DB, you can make a temporary table and use $_SESSION for store the name of table.

Answer (score 3):

Session variables can be stored in `$_SESSION`